# I need code snippet to embed the ethernet header with payload from secondary DPDK application to primary

Tags: dpdk

The architecture is as follows:

Secondary DPDK app  ------> Primary DPDK App ----> (EDIT)Interface

Inside my Secondary I have a vector of u8 bytes representing an L2 packet.
I want to send this L2 packet to the Primary App so the primary could send it to the internet.
From what I understood, the L2 packet has to be wrapped in mbuf in order to be able to put on a shared ring.
But I have no clue on how to do this wrapping.

**What I don't know exactly**: my packet is just a vector of bytes, how could I extract useful information out of it in order to fill the mbuf fields? And which fields of the mbuf should be filled minimally for this to work?

For better understanding, here is what should happen step by step:

1. Vector of bytes gets in secondary (doesn't matter how)
2. Secondary gets an mbuf from the shared mempool.
3. Secondary puts the vector inside the mbuf (the vector is an L2 packet)

- mbuf has many fields representing many things, so I don't know which field to fill and with what.

4. Secondary places the mbuf on a shared ring.
5. Primary grabs the mbuf from shared ring.
6. Primary send the mbuf to the internet.

This is what I coded so far, the secondary App is in Rust and primary App is in C language.

Secondary is here ([github](https://github.com/mihaidogaru2537/FirecrackerPlayground/blob/dpdk_component/firecracker/src/dpdk_component/src/client.rs)):

Remember, L2 Packet is just Vec, that is like [1, 222, 23, 34...], a simple array.

```
       // GETTING THE MBUF FROM SHARED MEMPOOL 
       let mut my_buffer = self.do_rte_mempool_get();
        while let Err(er) = my_buffer {
            warn!("rte_mempool_get failed, trying again.");
            my_buffer = self.do_rte_mempool_get();
            // it may fail if not enough entries are available.
        }
        warn!("rte_mempool_get success");
        // Let's just send an empty packet for starters.
        let my_buffer = my_buffer.unwrap();
        
        // HERE I SHOULD PUT THE L2 PACKET INSIDE THE MBUF.
        // MY L2 PACKET is a Vec<u8> 
        
        // NOW I PUT THE MBUF ON THE SHARED RING, BYE MBUF

        let mut res = self.do_rte_ring_enqueue(my_buffer);
        // it may fail if not enough room in the ring to enqueue
        while let Err(er) = res {
            warn!("rte_ring_enqueue failed, trying again.");
            res = self.do_rte_ring_enqueue(my_buffer);
        }
        warn!("rte_ring_enqueue success");
```

And Primary is here (it just gets mbufs from ring and has to send them with rte_eth_tx_burst()):

```
/* Run until the application is quit or killed. */
for (;;)
{
    // receive packets on rte ring
    // then send them to NIC


    struct rte_mbuf *bufs[BURST_SIZE];
    void *mbuf;

    if (rte_ring_dequeue(recv_ring, &mbuf) < 0) {
        continue;
    }

    printf("Received mbuf.\n");
    //for now I just want to test it out so I stop here
    continue;

    //* Send packet to port */
    bufs[0] = mbuf;
    uint16_t nbPackets = 1;
    const uint16_t nb_tx = rte_eth_tx_burst(port, 0,
                                            bufs, nbPackets);

    // /* Free any unsent packets. */
    if (unlikely(nb_tx < nbPackets))
    {   
        rte_pktmbuf_free(bufs[nbPackets]);
    }
```

If you have any questions please let me know!
As always, thanks for reading!

**UPDATE:** the dpdk primary wasn't actually connected to the internet. It is simply using an interface of a virtual machine. The DPDK secondary and primary are both running inside a virtual machine and the interface used by primary is connected to a host interface through a bridge. So I can watch the bridge in question on the host using tcpdump.

I tried something to put the L2 packet inside the mbuf on secondary and it looks like this:

(you can also check [github](https://github.com/mihaidogaru2537/FirecrackerPlayground/blob/dpdk_component/firecracker/src/dpdk_component/src/client.rs))

```
 // After receiving something on the channel
        // I want to send it to the primary DPDK
        // And the primary will send it to hardware NIC
        
        let mut my_buffer = self.do_rte_mempool_get();
        while let Err(er) = my_buffer {
            warn!("rte_mempool_get failed, trying again.");
            my_buffer = self.do_rte_mempool_get();
            // it may fail if not enough entries are available.
        }
        warn!("rte_mempool_get success");
        // Let's just send an empty packet for starters.
        let my_buffer = my_buffer.unwrap();
        let my_buffer_struct: *mut rte_mbuf = my_buffer as (*mut rte_mbuf);
        
       unsafe {
            // the packet buffer, not the mbuf
            let buf_addr: *mut c_void = (*my_buffer_struct).buf_addr;
            let mut real_buf_addr = buf_addr.offset((*my_buffer_struct).data_off as isize);
            //try to copy the Vec<u8> inside the mbuf
            copy(my_data.as_mut_ptr(), real_buf_addr as *mut u8, my_data.len());
            (*my_buffer_struct).data_len = my_data.len() as u16;
       };
```

(my_data is the Vec in the above code snippet)

Now, on the primary DPDK I am receiving those bytes which are the bytes of the L2 packet. I printed them and they are the same as in secondary which is great.

```
for (;;)
{
    // receive packets on rte ring
    // then send them to NIC


    struct rte_mbuf *bufs[BURST_SIZE];
    void *mbuf;
    unsigned char* my_packet;
    uint16_t data_len;
    uint16_t i = 0;

    if (rte_ring_dequeue(recv_ring, &mbuf) < 0) {
        continue;
    }

    printf("Received mbuf.\n");
    my_packet = ((unsigned char *)(*(struct rte_mbuf *)mbuf).buf_addr) + ((struct rte_mbuf *)mbuf)->data_off;
    data_len = ((struct rte_mbuf *)mbuf)->data_len;
    for (i = 0; i < data_len; i++) {
        printf("%d ", (uint8_t)my_packet[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");



    //for now I just want to test it out so I stop here
    // rte_pktmbuf_free(mbuf);
    // continue;

    //* Send packet to port */
    bufs[0] = (struct rte_mbuf *)mbuf;
    uint16_t nbPackets = 1;
    const uint16_t nb_tx = rte_eth_tx_burst(port, 0,
                                            bufs, nbPackets);

    // /* Free any unsent packets. */
    if (unlikely(nb_tx < nbPackets))
    {   
        rte_pktmbuf_free(bufs[nbPackets]);
    }
```

But the issue is that after sending the mbuf from primary with eth_tx_burst, I cannot see any packet while using tcpdump on the host.
So I am guessing I am not wrapping the packet inside the mbuf properly.
I hope it makes more sense.

Comment: is your question `my secondary RUST DPDK application is not embedding vector u8 buffer in mbuf format?`. If yes can you please share what is the error (if any) or what is mbuf content you get after preparing in secondary and primary using `rte_pktmbuf_dump`.

Comment: in the current code you have declared the variable `    let mut my_data: Vec<u8>; `. I am not able to find the actual buffer contents. Can you share the updated code.

Comment: @VipinVarghese regarding 1st comment: my question is more like how to embed the vector u8 in mbuf format. I am not getting any error because I did not write any code to do that because I do not know how. I did not change the content of the mbuf after getting it from the mempool, so it should be as default as possible. If you still want to see tht at pktmbuf_dump let me know and I will do it.

Comment: @VipinVarghese Regarding your 2nd comment: I think this is what you are looking for: line 615 here https://github.com/mihaidogaru2537/FirecrackerPlayground/blob/dpdk_component/firecracker/src/devices/src/virtio/net/device.rs 
That Vec<u8> from secondary is received through a channel which resides in this link (it's same project, another crate). It's a virtio device if that is of any help. Basically I am getting the packet out of a virtio device and giving it to Secondary.

Comment: RIght now if you take a look at 618, the packet is written on a tap interface. Long time goal is to stop feeding the packet through that TAP interface and communicate using DPDK only (it has nothing to do with the question but I thought some perspective might help. If it's just more confusing you can ignore this message)

Comment: so basically you do not have any error because there is no code to alloc and write the packet in mbuf in secondary, What you really need is a code snippet or sample code to do so, Basically, you need working code. So let me edit the question to reflect your intention.

Comment: this is bit confusing as per the diagram DPDK interface is connected to the Internet. But to send the packet to the internet via DPDK one needs the packet (in your vector u8). I am not able to find the original 618 packets (that is claimed to be send on tap interface). May I will put code snippet what you need to add and leave it you to decide

Comment: I added some update to the question. Basically I managed to transmit that Vec<u8> which contained the L2 packet from secondary to primary. But after sending the mbuf from primary to its interface,  I cannot see any traffic on that interface. (that interface is bridged to a host and I am running tcpdump on the host)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mihai, if one needs to create a DPDK buffer in secondary and send it via RTE_RING following are the steps to do so

1. Start the secondary application
2. Get the Mbuf pool ptr via `rte_mempool_lookup`
3. Allocate mbuf from mbuf pool via `rte_pktmbuf_alloc`
4. set minimum fields in mbuf such as `pkt_len, data_len, next and nb_segs` to appropriate values.
5. fetch the starting of the region to mem copy your custom packet with `rte_pktmbuf_mtod_offset or rte_pktmbuf_mtod`
6. then memcopy the content from user vector to DPDK area

Note: based on the checksum offload, actual frame len and chain mbuf mode other fields need to be updated.

code snippet

```
mbuf_ptr = rte_pktmbuf_alloc(mbuf_pool);
mbuf_ptr->data_len = [size of vector preferably under 1500];
mbuf_ptr->pkt_len = mbuf_ptr->data_len;
struct rte_ether_hdr *eth_hdr = rte_pktmbuf_mtod(created_pkt, struct rte_ether_hdr *);
rte_memcpy(&eth_addr, &user_buffer, mbuf_ptr->data_len);
```

Note: similar to the above code has been implemented in `Rust + C` wireguard to be enabled with DPDK.

Please rework with the above code into your code

```
            warn!("rte_mempool_get success");
            // Let's just send an empty packet for starters.
            let my_buffer = my_buffer.unwrap();
            let my_buffer_struct: *mut rte_mbuf = my_buffer as (*mut rte_mbuf);
            
           unsafe {
                // the packet buffer, not the mbuf
                let buf_addr: *mut c_void = (*my_buffer_struct).buf_addr;
                let mut real_buf_addr = buf_addr.offset((*my_buffer_struct).data_off as isize);
                //try to copy the Vec<u8> inside the mbuf
                copy(my_data.as_mut_ptr(), real_buf_addr as *mut u8, my_data.len());
                (*my_buffer_struct).data_len = my_data.len() as u16;
           };
            
            unsafe {
                warn!("Length of segment buffer: {}", (*my_buffer_struct).buf_len);
                warn!("Data offset: {}", (*my_buffer_struct).data_off);
                let buf_addr: *mut c_void = (*my_buffer_struct).buf_addr;
                let real_buf_addr = buf_addr.offset((*my_buffer_struct).data_off as isize);
                warn!("Address of buf_addr: {:?}", buf_addr);
                warn!("Address of buf_addr + data_off: {:?}", real_buf_addr);
                warn!("\n");
            };
```

Comment: Why is rte_pktmbuf_alloc used instead of rte_mempool_get ?

Comment: @Mihai rte_mempool_get is wrapper on top of  rte_mempool_get_bulk where number of objects is set 1. while rte_mbuf_alloc fetches mubf packet as 1 instance without any lock.

Comment: @Mihai if you find the answer helpful please accept and upvote to close the ticket.